# file has been created but when opened nothing is in it

Tags: android, file

I have an android app and simply i need to store data in a file. I need to use external storage to make it available for other applications too. 
im using this piece of code

```
BufferedWriter bw;
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/storage/sdcard0/download/themagicfile.txt", true));
                            bw.write("hi");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

which i got from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041007/write-to-txt-file-but-not-overwrite
I can see the file in the directory but when i open it there is nothing in it. i need to use `FileWriter` to make it appendable.
any suggestion

Comment: Also check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386441/filewriter-not-writing-to-file-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should also call

```
 bw.flush(); 
 bw.close();
```

rembember to add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
   try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/storage/sdcard0/download/themagicfile.txt", true));
        bw.write("hi");
        bw.flush();
    } (IOException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        bw.close();
      } (IOException e) { }
    }
```

Comment: I could see the text after this. But i needed to refresh the file manager in my device. it just doesnt show it write away. even if the usb Cable is not connected to laptop..why? is there any solutoin for that that i can use inside a code?